# jQuery Cloud Zoom getting invalid object initializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, eval

i combine all javascripts of a web site

it has some jQuery plugins like facebox, cloud zoom face box is working fine,

but there is an error with cloud zoom, **the error is on fire bug
invalid object initializer**

```
var a = {undefined}
```

**a variable comes with some eval function as below**

```
eval('var   a = {' + $(this).attr('rel') + '}');
relOpts = a;
```

**here i attached some codes which have error returns, can anyone help me, i tried lot but no results**

```
$.fn.CloudZoom = function (options) {
        // IE6 background image flicker fix
        try {
            document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
        } catch (e) {}
        this.each(function () {
            var relOpts, opts;
            // 
            eval('var   a = {' + $(this).attr('rel') + '}');
                    //error throw in below line
            relOpts = a;
            if ($(this).is('.cloud-zoom')) {
                $(this).css({
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check you HTML Code Attribute "rel".